# unbound method error message in printer call method

Tags: python

Here is part of the code; the parts which seem to be giving me the problem. This is of course part of a larger program. When I run it gives the error message:

```
unbound method start_data_printer() must be called with printer instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I have dealt with the error before but can't quite figure it out this time.

```
from start_geonode_correction_new_style_class_2 import data
## import from the data class

class printer(data):

    def start_data_printer(data): ## method to print from data class
            import csv
            generator_start = data.data_out_start() ## data_out_start: a
                                                    ## data sifting method in 
                                                    ## data class
            outfile = csv.writer(open('start_data_output.csv','wb'))
            for row in generator_start:
                print row[0:]
                outfile.writerows([row])
                ## writes output from data_func_start function to a .csv file
```

Below is the main class call to run the program

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS')
reader = open('converted_dataset_01_13_2014_added_top_new_data_01_29_14.csv', 'rb')
from data_printer import printer

class function_calls(object):
    if __name__=='__main__':

        data_set = printer(reader)
        printer.start_data_printer() ## this is where it says the error is
```

Comment: I would highly recommend to use camel case for class names e.g. Printer.

Comment: @ aisbaa: duelly noted.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `printer` is a class. You are trying to call printer method directly with class instead of object and you are not passing argument data to that method.

```
# create printer object
my_printer = printer()
# call method using object
my_printer.start_data_printer()
```

This will fix method calling issue. Now methods should be defined as:

```
class Printer(data):

     def start_data_printer(self, generator):
         generator_start = generator.get_start()
         self.calculate_something()
         ...
```